# How does a object in python find its available methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x

please help me on this topic : If I try to print object.**dict**, it only shows instance variables and not the methods where as classes do show it's variable and method functions.

If I consider powershell objects, then it does show it's method and properties and many more attributes.
              example : powershell_object | get-member

Comment: Methods are functions that belong to the objects's `__class__`, and to all the classes in it's class method-resolution order, `__class__.__mro__`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dir(obj)` and get the methods **and** instance variables, then you can filter them to only functions like this:

```
object_functions = {}
for obj_member in dir(obj):
    if callable(getattr(obj, obj_member)):
        object_functions[obj_member] = getattr(obj, obj_member)
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods are functions that belong to the objects's `__class__`, and to all the classes in it's class method-resolution order, which you can introspect using: `__class__.__mro__`

So consider:

```
In [15]: class A(object):
    ...:     def amethod(self): pass
    ...: class B(A):
    ...:     def bmethod(self): pass
    ...: class C(A):
    ...:     def cmethod(self): pass
    ...: class D(B, C):
    ...:     def dmethod(self): pass
    ...:

In [16]: d = D()

In [17]: vars(D)
Out[17]:
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              'dmethod': <function __main__.D.dmethod(self)>,
              '__doc__': None})
```

Note, `vars` just returns `__dict__`. Notice, `D.__dict__` only has `dmethod`. Now consider:

```
In [18]: D.__mro__
Out[18]: (__main__.D, __main__.B, __main__.C, __main__.A, object)

In [19]: from pprint import pprint


In [20]: for klass in D.__mro__:
    ...:     print(klass, end=' '); pprint(vars(klass))
    ...:
<class '__main__.D'> mappingproxy({'__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              'dmethod': <function D.dmethod at 0x106e72048>})
<class '__main__.B'> mappingproxy({'__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              'bmethod': <function B.bmethod at 0x106e72ea0>})
<class '__main__.C'> mappingproxy({'__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              'cmethod': <function C.cmethod at 0x106e72158>})
<class '__main__.A'> mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
              'amethod': <function A.amethod at 0x106e72400>})
<class 'object'> mappingproxy({'__class__': <attribute '__class__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__delattr__': <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__dir__': <method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__doc__': 'The most base type',
              '__eq__': <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__format__': <method '__format__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__ge__': <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__gt__': <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__hash__': <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__init_subclass__': <method '__init_subclass__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__le__': <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__lt__': <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__ne__': <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x104ebe518>,
              '__reduce__': <method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__reduce_ex__': <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__setattr__': <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__sizeof__': <method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__str__': <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>,
              '__subclasshook__': <method '__subclasshook__' of 'object' objects>})
```